# CodeMirror text width for custom font

Tags: codemirror, react-codemirror

I have a custom theme for CM, important part is just this:

```
.CodeMirror, .CodeMirror * {
  font-family: "Roboto Mono" !important;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Using this theme causes the text to be measured incorrectly at first render, but it looks good after the editor updates:

[image]

Is there any way I could force the Editor/Doc to re-measure the text? Couldn't find any API methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the CSS that you provided and it works very fine.
Just you don't need to use the `.CodeMirror *`

I think that your problem may be due to something else.
Try  to call `editor.refresh();` after the page loaded.

Comment: Good news !  